# Dapper.net "where ... in" query doesn't work with PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, dapper

The following query always produces the error **"42601: syntax error at or near "$1"**
".

```
connection.Query<CarStatsProjection>(
                @"select manufacturer, model, year, AVG(price) as averageprice, AVG(miles) as averagemiles, COUNT(*) as count
                        from products
                        where manufacturer IN @manufacturers 
                            AND model IN @models
                            AND year IN @years
                        group by manufacturer, model, year",
                new { manufacturers = new[] { "BMW", "AUDI" }, 
                      models = new[] { "M4", "A3" }, 
                      years = new[] { 2016, 2015 } });
```

I have got around this by creating a method below and calling it inline to build the SQL query for now. Would like to know if Dapper can handle this with the object param though?

```
 public static string ToInSql(this IEnumerable<object> values)
    {
        var flattened = values.Select(x => $"'{x}'");
        var flatString = string.Join(", ", flattened);

        return $"({flatString})";
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code causing the error? The SQL string has two parameters (manufacturers and models), but there are three parameters being passed to Dapper (manufactures, models, and years); but, Dapper will disregard the unused parameter so that's not the issue. The use of the IN clause and Dapper conventions is correct as well. The SQL string is prefaced with the String Interpolation symbol, but there is no String Interpolation occurring. There's something else in your code that appears to be missing from your post; maybe the String Interpolation?

Comment: Hi there - it was because I had already started using the ToInSql() method below and just undid a few things. I have reverted it properly as you can see in the updated post. Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

PostgreSQL `IN` operator doesn't support array (or any other collection) as parameter, only a normal list (the one which you're generating with the `ToInSql` method), for PostgreSQL you need to use `ANY` operator, like this:

```
SELECT manufacturer, model, year, AVG(price) as averageprice, AVG(miles) as averagemiles, COUNT(*) as count
FROM products
WHERE manufacturer = ANY(@manufacturers)
AND model = ANY(@models)
AND year = ANY(@years)
GROUP BY manufacturer, model, year
```

Comment: I am receiving an error: Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 22P03: invalid array flags; any idea?

Comment: I have upvoted this because it gave me the much needed hint.  At the same time, I have a "more complete top to bottom" answer here.  @MuriloKunze/Other future readers, you may want to check this answer out for the complete magic syntax sugar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75098182/214977