# Npgsql.PostgresException : 42601: syntax error at or near "$2"

Tags: c#, psql, dapper

I'm using C# and Dapper to fetch from a table using a PARTITION. I'm receiving the following error:

Npgsql.PostgresException : 42601: syntax error at or near "$2"

My SQL is:

```
WITH G AS
  (SELECT id,
          category,
          sub_category AS SubCategory,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SOURCE,
                                          category,
                                          sub_category
                             ORDER BY id DESC) AS rn
   FROM public.my_transactions
   WHERE SOURCE = @Source
     AND category in @Categories)
SELECT *
FROM G
WHERE rn = 1
```

The `$2` must be a reference to `Categories` right? I tried changing the SQL to use `category = Any(@Categories)` but that didn't help.

My C# code looks like this:

```
var q = _context.Query<object>(mySql,
    new { Source = "Test", Categories = new string[] { "Price Action" } });
```

Is this possible? What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I'm also open to alternative ways to accomplish this - finding the first row for each source, category, sub_category combo. I tried a sub-query, but it took several seconds to complete. I've been playing around with `GROUP BY`, but I can't quite get it right. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Dapper's `in @something` facility rewrites the SQL to something that works on multiple providers; however, it is possible that the syntax used doesn't work with postgresql - I'll need to check; but yes, the $2 is coming from Npgsql's additional rewrite of the SQL - you *might* find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188558/dapper-net-where-in-query-doesnt-work-with-postgresql useful

Comment: I wrote the SQL using pgAdmin and it works from there (without the @ parms). I also tried the `= Any()` solution - that didn't work. I can refactor to fetch the data and sort it myself, so it's not a hard blocker for me . . . but it would be nice if it worked.